# ActionBuilder to accept IO[Result] instead of Future[Result]

Tags: scala, scalaz, playframework-2.3

I wrote a small example to use the IO monad from scalaz within the play framework. The example below works as expected:

```
object IOAction {
  def apply(action:IO[Result]):Result = action.unsafePerformIO
}

class ExampleController extends Controller {
  val now:IO[DateTime] = IO { DateTime.now }

  def index = Action { request => 
    IOAction { 
      now.map { dateTime => Ok(views.html.index(dateTime)) }
    }
  }
}
```

However, I'm wondering if the use of a play ActionBuilder might result in a slightly less verbose API. Ideally, I would like to write:

```
class ExampleController extends Controller {
  val now:IO[DateTime] = IO { DateTime.now }

  def index = IOAction { request => 
    now.map { dateTime => Ok(views.html.index(dateTime)) }
  }
}
```

I got stuck because the `invokeBlock` function seems to be fixed to the `Future[Result]` type.

```
def invokeBlock[A](request: R[A], block: P[A] => Future[Result]): Future[Result]
```

Does anyone know a workaround where IOAction behaves just the same as Action (ie. an optional request parameter and body parser)?

Comment: Are you sure you use play-2.0, not play-2.2 or play-2.3 ?

Comment: I'm using Play 2.3.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't the latter example work, if you redefine `IOAction`:

```
object IOAction {
  def apply(io: Request[AnyContent] => IO[Result]): Action[AnyContent] =
    Action { (request: Request[AnyContent]) => io(request).unsafePerformIO }
}
```

And in `Controller` object you could do

```
def foo(): Handler = IOAction { request =>
  Ok("foo").point[IO]
}
```

I.e. `Future` is asynchronous (IO) computation, where `IO` is synchronous. Transformation from `IO` to `Future` is thus easy.

---

The combination of `IO` and `ActionBuilder` doesn't really workout.
`ActionBuilder` is not made with `IO` in mind. It has

```
final def apply(block: ⇒ Result): Action[AnyContent]
final def apply(block: (R[AnyContent]) ⇒ Result): Action[AnyContent]
final def async(block: ⇒ Future[Result]): Action[AnyContent]
final def async(block: R[AnyContent]) ⇒ Future[Result]): Action[AnyContent]
```

You can make a trait extending `ActionBuilder[R]` and providing, say:

```
final def io(block: => Result): Action[AnyContent]
final def io(block R[AnyContent] => Result): Action[AnyContent]
```

Then you could define:

```
object IOAction extends IOActionBuilder[Request] { /* ... */ }
```

And use it as:

```
 def foo = IOAction.io { request => 
   Ok("foo").point[IO]
 }
```

This is almost exactly the same what we defined first, not so directly though.

---

In [ActionComposition.scala](https://github.com/mariussoutier/PlayBasics/blob/master/play-2.2-migration/app/controllers/ActionComposition.scala) interest is in
composing actions, not providing the *base action*.

Comment: The first solution doesn't work if you want to access the request parameter as well, the second solution doesn't work either because to use the IOAction in combination with the ActionBuilder the `io` parameter of IOAction should be of type `Action[A]` I guess. See: https://github.com/mariussoutier/PlayBasics/blob/master/play-2.2-migration/app/controllers/ActionComposition.scala